# Should I flag an answer that isn't relevant for the question as "not an answer"?

Tags: discussion, flags

I've flagged [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/231693/how-do-you-unlock-the-drift-king-achievement-in-rocket-league/231694#231694) as "not an answer" and my flag was declined, but I'm not sure why.

The given reason for declining was as follows:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

However, I didn't flag it because I thought it was wrong, but because I felt that it doesn't attempt to answer the question.

To my understanding, the question is basically:

> How do I get the achievement that says "Perform a 180 powerslide with both the Cristiano and Spinner Wheels"? (with focus on what counts as a powerslide).

The answer was basically:

> "These wheels don't exist. Here is a list of wheels in the game" (and thus it didn't attempt to answer the question).

Now, that the wheels don't exist was wrong, but even if that sentence wasn't there, a list of wheels still doesn't attempt to answer any part of the question in my opinion.

My question is: Is it justified to flag a post like this, where the answer deals with a similar topic and the poster had the intention to help, but the post doesn't actually include an answer to the question?

Or is this type of flag only for completely off-topic things like "Thank you" answers etc.? Should I have flagged it differently or should I just downvote answers that don't answer the question like this (regardless of quality)?

Comment: I think the part of that answer that was attempting to answer the question wasn't the list of wheels, but rather then "There are two new wheels in the DLC.", implying that maybe the person needs that. The list of wheels was the attempt at proof they didn't currently exist in the game (and thus probably were being introduced in DLC).

Comment: @Sterno Question asker here. Saying that there are new wheels in the DLC when the question asks how to use those new wheels to get a certain achievement (suggesting that the asker already knows how to get them) seems very off-topic. The question clearly stated that I had used both wheels numerous times. That said, I think he meant well, but possibly should have refrained from posting a full list of all previous wheels and instead commented something like "for anyone wondering, this pertains to the two wheels introduced in the new DLC".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you should flag things that are tangential and don't address the actual question as not an answer.

Moderators are, unfortunately, not infallible. I've corrected the error in this case.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if I was just using it wrong. Thanks.