# Why was this other flag rejected?

Tags: support, flags

I flagged [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92987/does-elise-continue-to-take-damage-during-rappel/270978#270978) as "Not an answer" since it doesn't try to address the question, which is specifically about Damage over Time abilities, which Chum the Waters isn't. According to [this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10790/should-i-flag-an-answer-that-isnt-relevant-for-the-question-as-not-an-answer), an answer that doesn't address the question can be flagged for not being an answer. What am I missing?

Comment: I interpret this as a bad answer. As such I have downvoted.  While presently at a score of -2, at -3'the question disappears to all lower rep users, and if left unanswered, will be deleted.

Comment: [Another relevant meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4265/flagging-answers-that-answer-a-completely-different-question/4267#4267).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize the difference in the abilities (I don't League), so that's my mistake. I've gone ahead and deleted the question.

Comment: I don't know if I wasn't very clear, but my point is that the example given by the answer is not a damage over time, so it doesn't address the question specifically. Is that wrong? Is the meta post I linked outdated?

Comment: No, that's an anecdote. It has zero bearing on actually answering the question.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer No, you're right, that's my mistake. I wasn't aware of the difference, since I don't play LoL. As I mentioned above, though, it looks like the asker is trying to answer the question...they just completely misunderstood what it was, so I've gone ahead and deleted it. In the future, though, I'd suggest leaving a comment on answers if it looks like the answering misunderstood the question, in addition to flagging (i.e. "The asker is specifically asking about DOTs, but Chum the Waters isn't a DOT")

Comment: @Wipqozn Understood. I don't League either so I wasn't too sure about leaving a comment, but I definitely should have in retrospect.