# Why was this flag rejected as well?

Tags: support, flags

I flagged [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45643/does-resolving-the-civil-war-make-areas-inaccessible/271307#271307) as "Not an answer", since it doesn't try to address the question, which is specifically about accessibility and being locked out of gameplay.  According to [this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10790/should-i-flag-an-answer-that-isnt-relevant-for-the-question-as-not-an-answer), an answer that doesn't address the question can be flagged for not being an answer. What am I missing?

Comment: How about making a meta question for every rejected flag is not a thing that you do?

Comment: @badp Can you elaborate? Do you mean flagging or posting these questions? I'd really love to know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm taking issue with the fact that you asked three different meta questions in a row with very similar titles about three different flags. You might be right on the flags having merit, but [flooding meta like this](http://i.imgur.com/LF9FhJG.png) does not set the conversation in a productive tone.

Comment: @badp Am I not supposed to ask multiple questions if I have more than one? I [asked for the appropriate course of action beforehand](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11741/what-to-do-about-declined-flags-i-still-believe-are-correct) and I happened to have three flags I was confused about.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't realize you had multiple flags you wanted to ask about all at once. I've made an edit my answer to address this, but if you have multiple flags you want to ask about then just make on meta for all of them, as @badp suggested.

Comment: It's okay to have several questions, but by asking several questions with largely identical titles and very terse bodies in the space of a few minutes, you came across as though you wish to pick a fight. The body of [this question in particular](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11743/why-was-this-flag-rejected) is missing any details on your rationale behind the flag. While I don't know if lumping together similar rejected flags is good advice in the general case, the answers you received are largely identical. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's attempting to answer the question, although it's doing a poor job of it. The attempt to answer is at the bottom of the answer:

> But thats only lore changes, gameplay barely changes at all.

It's poorly written, but what the answerer was trying to answer the question.

The thing to keep in mind is that [the not an answer flag isn't intended for low quality answers](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/not-an-answer-flag-are-not-intended-for-low-quality-answers), it's meant for posts which don't even attempt to answer the question like "Me too!" or "I'm having a similar problem except..."

> **Not an Answer:** This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

So just remember that so long as the post is trying to answer the question, then it is an answer. If the answer is bad, then downvote + maybe comment, but don't flag for deletion.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I thought the bit you quoted was specifically about the capital changing, not about the results of the war in general.

Comment: A single sentence in a paragraph that barely answers it isn't really worth keeping, in my opinion.

Comment: @Frank It's still an attempt to answer the question, though, so it shouldn't be flagged as not an answer, no matter how low of quality it is.

Comment: @Wipqozn No, but it *should* be downvoted.  And then deleted through the low quality queue.